# Beautify html with js-beautify from command line

Tags: js-beautify

I have installed js-beautify on Linux with Python 3.5. It does a fine job beautifying JavaScript -- its default behavior.

According to the readme info at https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify (under the heading "Options"), js-beautify can also beautify html and css using the --type command line option.

**If I use the following command:**

```
js-beautify --type html myfile.html
```

**it replies with:**

```
"option --type not recognized"
```

**I have also tried:**

```
js-beautify --html myfile.html
```

Does anyone know the how to beautify html (or css) with js-beautify using the command line (with Python)?

Comment: There is no python implementation of the html beautifier at this time.  You have to run the javascript implementation.

Comment: @BitwiseMan Yes there is: `pip install jsbeautifier`. It even says so [right in the package package README](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify). It's just that it doesn't really do anything useful AFAICS - my input is HTML in a single line without spaces and line breaks and the oputput is... exactly the same unless I force wrap-line-length but then the result still is ugly and even wrong. So that tool doesn't seem to be up to the job, at least for HTML. **To OP**: `--html` works for me (except for the "minor issue" just described).

Comment: @Mörre - I'm a maintainer of the project. The project includes a node/web javascript implementation and a python implementation, with a unified README.  You make a good point that the README should be clearer about this: The python implementation does not beautify html.  Only the node/web implementation handles html.  I'll update the README shortly.